# fundrawtransaction with watch-only address

Tags: bitcoind

I am trying to fund transaction with watch-only addresses:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getbalance '' 1 true
0.38810000

$ bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction '[]' '{"3Qxjvxyg9Pf67JU9MBNKVpJQ9rmALVnjt3":0.00001}'
020000000001e80300000000000017a914ff4432c8022b550a66b4c0a9c398962c3723ba278700000000

$  bitcoin-cli fundrawtransaction 020000000001e80300000000000017a914ff4432c8022b550a66b4c0a9c398962c3723ba278700000000 '{"includeWatching" : true}'
error code: -4
error message:
Insufficient funds
```

The idea is to sing the transaction later on different offline wallet.

Is this possible?

I can not use 'fundrawtransaction' directly on offline wallet, because it is offline and have no blockchain downloaded.

## update:

yes, I know about potential problems with fee and change address. I am currently exploring possibilities.

Comment: For `fundrawtransaction` to work, you need more than just a watch-only address, as it needs to be able to predict the witness size needed to spend them. If you use `importaddress` or `importmulti` with just an address, this is not possible. If you use `importpubkey` or `importmulti` with full keys/scripts, or with a descriptor, it will. You can test this by checking `getaddressinfo` on the addresses that the coins are currently assigned to.

Comment: I also noticed I can not sign transaction if blockchain is not synchronized